# Is there a way for me to shrink a regex query?

Tags: regex, sed

Let's say I have a regex query like:

```
hund|seehund|präriehund
```

Visually we can see this can be shrunk down to:

```
(see|prärie)?hund
```

Now, I have a giant regex query where noting the similarities is very hard. Is there a way I can insert a regex query and have a tool shrink it down to be as small as possible (or reverse, take a small regex query and expand it)? I know it won't look appealing but my goal is for smallest size, think code golf.

To be specific, I will use this with BSD sed.

Sorry if this is off topic, wasn't sure where else to put it.

Comment: There are online examples https://www.dcode.fr/regular-expression-simplificator or library examples https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Optimizer, but typically good design and manual review is how it is done.

Comment: LOL I assume this works well in most cases but I got `hund|se{2}hund|präriehund`, two bites *larger* than the source. Thanks though, I did not see the website when looking

Comment: ha! The algorithm behind the online version is likely quite primitive. The perl library would probably be a better bet, though again it will have limitations of course.

Comment: Sadly I know nothing about perl, i would test this but i lack knowledge on perl

Comment: There's also https://myregextester.com/ which has an optimize feature, but for your sample it gives a result that is both longer and less efficient than your proposed factorization (it extracts the ending "e" of "see"&"prärie" in addition to using non-capturing groups) : `(?:(?:präri|se)e)?hund`. Still, that seems like a more solid base than the dcode.fr one if you want to use an online tool to do the bulk of the work.

Comment: convert to NFA, then convert back to regex? https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-convert-finite-automata-to-regular-expressions